# Apply Function for Dataframe - Can I Reference Previous Row?

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I'm working with a dataframe in which one of the columns is a boolean vector. The boolean vector indicates if its row begins a new 'group' (the data is in order by this column). Here's a trivial example:

```
    d <- data.frame(element=c(1:10),newGroup=c("TRUE","FALSE","FALSE","FALSE","TRUE","FALSE","TRUE","FALSE","FALSE","TRUE"))
> d
   element newGroup
1        1     TRUE
2        2    FALSE
3        3    FALSE
4        4    FALSE
5        5     TRUE
6        6    FALSE
7        7     TRUE
8        8    FALSE
9        9    FALSE
10      10     TRUE
```

I now want to create an index of the distinct groups. To do this, I need only to do something like the following:

```
group <- vector("numeric",nrow(d))
```

then, for each row, r, in `2:nrow(d):`

```
if(d[r, c("newGroup")==TRUE)
{
   group[r] <- group[r-1]
}else{
   group[r] <- group[r-1]+1
}
```

I was trying to accomplish this with the `apply` function, as follows but I'm having trouble with applying a function to the rows of my data frame, because the function acts on specific elements in my rows and relies on information from previous rows. Is apply the right way to go here? When I try to implement something like the above, I get the error `"Error in`[.data.frame`(r, "indx") : undefined columns selected Called from: [.data.frame(r, "indx") debug: length(cols) == 1"`.

Here is my code:

```
d$indx <- 1:nrow(d)
d$RunID <- as.numeric("")
d$RunID[1] <- 1

newRun <- function(r)
{
  r <- as.data.frame(r)
  if(d$newGroup[r$indx]==TRUE)
  {
    group <- d$RunID[r$indx-1]
  }else{
    group <- d$RunID[r$indx-1] + 1
  }
  return(group)
}

Runs <- apply(d[2:nrow(d),],1,newRun)
d$RunID[2:nrow(d)] <- Runs
```

Comment: What's your expected output? Does `d$group = cumsum(d$newGroup == "TRUE")` achieve what you want?

Comment: `"TRUE"` and `TRUE` are not the same in R either.

Comment: @Marius, yes that does achieve what I want. Thank you, I wasn't aware of this function.

Comment: If they are indeed `TRUE` and not `"TRUE"`, just `cumsum(d$newGroup)` would do.